# How to set Dropdown value in angular4?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular4-forms

I have a dropdown to which i am passing some values, now i want to set the selection of the dropdown, how can i do it

**here is my code**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  dataset: any[] = [
    { value: 'one', key: 1 },
    { value: 'two', key: 2 },
    { value: 'three', key: 3 },
    { value: 'four', key: 4 }
  ]

  selectionChanged(data) {
    debugger;
  }
}
```

html

```
<div>
  <select (change)="selectionChanged($event.target.value)">
      <option *ngFor="let item of dataset;let i=index " [value]="item.key" >{{item.value}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use  `[(ngModel)]` directive.

HTML

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" (change)="selectionChanged($event.target.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let item of dataset;let i=index " [value]="item.key" >{{item.value}}</option>
</select>
```

Typescript

```
this.selectedItem = dataset[0].key;
```